# why does controller-runtime say resource 'not found' while updating resource that exists?

Tags: kubernetes

I have written a k8s controller with kubebuilder which reconciles my CustomResource object (MyResource).

During update, controller-runtime gives me an error 'not found' even though my resource exists on the cluster.

```
func (r *MyResourceReconciler) updateStatus(ctx context.Context, myResource *myResourcev1.MyResource, neoStatus *myResourcev1.MyResourceStatus) error {
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(&myResource.Status, neoStatus) {
        myResource.Status = *neoStatus
        err := r.Status().Update(ctx, myResource)
        return err

    }
    return nil
}
```

Can someone please help me troubleshoot this error? I'm stuck because I can do a GET on the resource using kubectl on the cluster & yet controller-runtime says 'not found'.

Comment: @RakeshGupta The update function does not require namespace, I'm passing the object that I've already fetched using a GET call

Comment: what about the context - is it using the correct ns?

Comment: Not modified the context at all, it is directly getting trickled down from the Reconcile() call..

Comment: see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65120965/operator-sdk-controller-failed-to-update-custom-resource-status

Comment: That's different from my issue -- in my case it says 'Not found', it doesn't give the usual 'object has been modified error'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue myself using:

`r.Update(ctx, myResource)` instead of `r.Status().Update(ctx, myResource)`

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue while another type works perfectly. Finally I found the root cause.

You need to have this mark above your struct to enable status subresources.

```
//+kubebuilder:subresource:status
```

https://book-v1.book.kubebuilder.io/basics/status_subresource.html